# For the linear mapping from $E$ to $F$, show that $|r (\phi) - r(\psi)| \leq r (\phi + \psi) \leq r(\phi) + (\psi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 81, it is asked that

> Given two linear mappings $\phi : E \to F$ and $\psi : E \to F$, where $E$ and $F$ are vector spaces, prove
>   that $$|r (\phi) - r(\psi)| \leq r (\phi + \psi) \leq r(\phi) +
> (\psi),$$ where $r(\phi)$ is the rank of the map $\phi$ and | | denotes the absolute value.

I can see much of the result intuitively, but having trouble putting it in a formal context.

I mean the cases where $\phi(x) = - \psi (x)$ will lower the middle if there is any, so I can understand the right inequality.

So, what I am asking is that how can we prove this result rigorously ?

Comment: What are $E$ and $F$ here? And what is $|\_|$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ K_1, K_2 $ be the kernels of $ \phi, \psi $ respectively. Without loss of generality, assume $ \dim K_1 \geq  \dim K_2 $, and pick a subspace $ W $ of $ K_1 $ such that $ K_1 = (K_1 \cap K_2) \oplus W $, by basis extension, for example. Then, since $ W \cap K_2 = \{ 0 \} $ by construction, we have that

$$ \dim W \leq \dim \textrm{Im}(\phi + \psi) = r(\phi + \psi) $$

along with

$$ \dim W = \dim K_1 - \dim (K_1 \cap K_2) \geq \dim K_1 - \dim K_2 = (\dim E - r(\phi)) - (\dim E - r(\psi)) = r(\psi) - r(\phi) = |r(\phi) - r(\psi)| $$

which implies the first inequality.

For the second inequality, simply note that $ \textrm{Im}(\phi + \psi) \subset \textrm{Im} \phi + \textrm{Im} \psi $, and take dimensions to obtain the result.